# how to fix firebase json parse error while saving data to realtime db?

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm saving data to firebase realtime db all works fine until these json string arrives. it shows invalid json parse

```
{
   "biz_title":"UCO BANK ATM in Perambakkam",
   "list_price":0,
   "campaign_id":0,
   "phone":"044 2765 5322",
   "biz_c_status":"closed",
   "biz_date":"20-07-19 09:17:28",
   "biz_ads_purchase_packages":null,
   "biz_view_count":0,
   "id":337,
   "biz_modified":"08-09-19 14:07:57",
   "plan_id":0,
   "g_address":"UCO Bank ATM, Perambakkam, Tamil Nadu, India",
   "biz_type":"listing",
   "biz_ads_purchase_date":null,
   "gst_number":null,
   "price_status":"notsay",
   "email":null,
   "biz_reported":null,
   "aadhar_number":null,
   "mappin":null,
   "biz_status":"publish",
   "latitude":13.0391786,
   "biz_logo":null,
   "biz_tagline":null,
   "gallery":null,
   "new_planid":0,
   "list_price_to":0,
   "biz_name":"uco-bank-atm-in-perambakkam",
   "biz_author":1,
   "biz_reported_by":0,
   "longitude":79.81525629999999,
   "contact_person":null,
   "claimed_section":"not_claimed",
   "biz_description":"UCO Bank, formerly United Commercial Bank, established in 1943 in Kolkata, is a major government-owned commercial bank of India. During FY 2013-14, its total business was \u20b9 4.55 lakh crore. Based on 2014 data, it is ranked 1860 on Forbes Global 2000 List. UCO Bank was ranked 294th among India's most trusted brands according to the Brand Trust Report 2014, a study conducted by Trust Research Advisory. It was a rise of 796 ranks considering it was listed at the 1090th position among Indias most trusted brands in the Brand trust Report 2013. As of 30 March 2017 the bank had 4,000 plus service units 49 zonal offices spread all over India. It also has two overseas branches in Singapore and Hong Kong. UCO Bank's headquarters is on BTM Sarani, Kolkata.\r\n\r\n*source: Wikipedia"
}
```

this is the result fetched from firebase rest request

```
{
  "error" : "Invalid data; couldn't parse JSON object, array, or value."
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just debug it ? Try for example to remove `biz_description` child (value too long ?) and try again. It shouldn't take a lot of time to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: I tried and it works fine.